# LateInitializationError: Field '___' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter

I got LateInitializationError: Field '_subjects@100178445' has not been initialized Error for Following Code.

Json Response as below.

```
{
  "success": 1,
  "subject": [
    {
      "subject_id": "5e32874c714fa",
      "subject_name": "Account",
      "image": "upload/subject/Account.png",
      "active": "1",
      "standard_id": "5d1594e283e1a",
      "medium_id": "5d15938aa1344"
    },
    {
      "subject_id": "5da9ff659fb7c",
      "subject_name": "Biology",
      "image": "upload/subject/03_logo-1164x484.png",
      "active": "1",
      "standard_id": "5d1594e283e1a",
      "medium_id": "5d15938aa1344"
    },
    {
      "subject_id": "5da9ff990b1c6",
      "subject_name": "Chemisty",
      "image": "upload/subject/02_logo-1168x490.png",
      "active": "1",
      "standard_id": "5d1594e283e1a",
      "medium_id": "5d15938aa1344"
    },
    {
      "subject_id": "5de76afbd064e",
      "subject_name": "Computer",
      "image": "upload/subject/07_logo-1169x486.png",
      "active": "1",
      "standard_id": "5d1594e283e1a",
      "medium_id": "5d15938aa1344"
    },
    {
      "subject_id": "5d788906c431b",
      "subject_name": "Devsatya Paperset March 2020",
      "image": "upload/subject/04_logo-1174x491.png",
      "active": "1",
      "standard_id": "5d1594e283e1a",
      "medium_id": "5d15938aa1344"
    }
  ]
}
```

Model class as bellow in subject_model.dart file.

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final subjectByUser = subjectByUserFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

SubjectByUser subjectByUserFromJson(String str) =>
    SubjectByUser.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String subjectByUserToJson(SubjectByUser data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class SubjectByUser {
  SubjectByUser({
    required this.success,
    required this.subject,
  });

  int success;
  List<Subject> subject;

  factory SubjectByUser.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => SubjectByUser(
        success: json["success"],
        subject:
            List<Subject>.from(json["subject"].map((x) => Subject.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "success": success,
        "subject": List<dynamic>.from(subject.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Subject {
  Subject({
    required this.subjectId,
    required this.subjectName,
    required this.image,
    required this.active,
    required this.standardId,
    required this.mediumId,
  });

  String subjectId;
  String subjectName;
  String image;
  String active;
  String standardId;
  String mediumId;

  factory Subject.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Subject(
        subjectId: json["subject_id"],
        subjectName: json["subject_name"],
        image: json["image"],
        active: json["active"],
        standardId: json["standard_id"],
        mediumId: json["medium_id"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "subject_id": subjectId,
        "subject_name": subjectName,
        "image": image,
        "active": active,
        "standard_id": standardId,
        "medium_id": mediumId,
      };
}
```

I created Function as below in apimanager.dart file

```
class ApiManager {
  static const String subjectUrl =
      "http://192.168.43.160/sahjanand/api/subject/get_by_user_plan?user_id=609cab2cd5b6c&order_id=1620889722609cd07a601af469889697609cab2cd5b6c&standard_id=5d1594e283e1a&medium_id=5d15938aa1344";

  static Future<List<SubjectByUser>> getSubjectByUser() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(subjectUrl));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final List<SubjectByUser> subjects =
            subjectByUserFromJson(response.body) as List<SubjectByUser>;
        print(subjects);
        return subjects;
      } else {
        return <SubjectByUser>[];
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // ignore: deprecated_member_use
      return <SubjectByUser>[];
    }
  }
}
```

And view code in homepage.dart file as bellow.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late List<SubjectByUser> _subjects;
  late bool _loading;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _loading = true;
    ApiManager.getSubjectByUser().then((subjects) {
      setState(() {
        _subjects = subjects;
        _loading = false;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_loading ? 'Loading...' : 'Subjects'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: null == _subjects ? 0 : _subjects.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              SubjectByUser subjectByUser = _subjects[index];
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(subjectByUser.success.toString()),
                subtitle: Text(subjectByUser.subject.length.toString()),
              );
            }),
       
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i got the LateInitializationError: Field '_subjects@100178445' has not been initialized Error.
So please help me how i solve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling _subjects in ListView.builder to compare, but by that time _subjects are not initalized, So it throws an error, You can initialise
_subjects as empty list

```
final _subjects = <SubjectByUser>[];
```

then once you got data, you can add all to it.

```
 ApiManager.getSubjectByUser().then((subjects) {
      setState(() {
       _subject..clear()..addAll(subjects);
        _loading = false;
      });
    });
```

and in itemCount, you can simply have

```
itemCount: _subjects.length,
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like:

```
child: _subjects != null  && _subjects.length.length > 0 ? ListView.builder(...) : CircularProgressIndicator();
```

Comment: Okay Sir, i eliminate the error but in setstate after _loading = false; line i put print(_subjects.toString()); and put break point  so there is no record in List. when i hower on _subjects there is List (0 Items). and its print only [].

Comment: THat means there is an error in your API since it is not returning the results you want

Comment: If `_subjects` is `late`, you cannot check if it's initialized.  The whole point of `late` is to disallow reading from a variable before it's initialized.  If checking it first is necessary, the variable instead should be nullable.

Comment: If it is [], it means it has no elements in it. So you don't put any data into the list. Maybe the API don't give back any data.

Comment: yes sir you are right, when i created model class from app.quicktype.io i forgot to put response between [ ] braces. i can put the new model class then can you help me to how i can get the inner list object and display in lisview?